# Move in stock/out of stock inline with title

Tags: magento-2.1, stock, title

in my theme, I need to display either "in stock" or "out of stock" in detail page. it's shown by default. I needed to display it right after the title. in one line.
I moved in stock inside title block. but the problem is, There is a `<h1>` tag inside the title.phtml file and I need in stock to be `<span>` inside that `'.
I can't move further in XML. Can't edit title.phtml to put span because when I do, it will affect for the every title instances inside my project.

How can I put a span inside h1 tag and instruct it to only display when on a product view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new template (for example `product_title.phtml`) and only change the template in the `catalog_product_view.xml` of your module or theme:

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">path/to/product_title.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

This way only the title template for that specific page is changed and you can still just put your `<span>` in there.

Comment: Hi, how do I set the path? is it something like, "Magento_Catalog/templates/products/view/view_title.phtml" or should I use just /products/view/filename.phtml?

Comment: It depends, if you put it in the `Magento_Catalog/templates`-folder of your design, then just use the relative path. For example: `products/view/view_title.phtml`. If your template is provided by another module (for example, your own module) then you should prefix it. For example: `Vendor_Module::products/view/view_title.phtml`.

Comment: Something like this?

<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">products/view/view_title.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>

just the relative path right? no need to put module name and other path elements? (if im working with current module in this question its catalog)

Comment: With this setup you have to put your template in `app/design/frontend/[PACKAGE]/[THEME]/Magento_Catalog/templates/products/view/view_title.phtml`.